# send multiple value from onclick function to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to send multiple data from on click function to jquery function like this code.

When I click on my button I get `[object Object]undefined]` in alert box

Code :

```js
$(function() {
  $("#button").click(function myf(data1, data2) {
    alert(data1 + data2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="button" onclick="myf('hello','word');">click</a>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You're binding two click event listeners! One using `.click()` and the other using `onclick` attribute!

Comment: You're registering 2 event listeners, and there's no point in passing the data from the HTML if you're binding the events on the element's `id`. The `id` must be unique, so you might as well code the data into the function.

Comment: What's wrong with the javascript listener you've added? Why do you need a jQuery one also?

Comment: I have not received any valid result from any answer yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using 2 event that will both try to listen to the onclick event
you can remove one of them like so :

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
  alert('hello' + 'word');
   });
});
</script>
```

An id is always unique so you can put your value directly into the function.

if you really want to use jquery you can use this:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
var data = $(this).data('params').split('|');
alert(data[0] + data[1]);
});
```

And this for the html :

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<a href="#" id="button" data-params='hello|world'>click</a>
```

Comment: helllo word not fixed value

Comment: @mody can you explain what those value are exaclty then and is jquery really neccesary because javascript could be a simple solution

Comment: i have tow value inside function from button (show in my question ).. when i clcik on button i want the value send to jquery function .. i have another code to useing those tow value but i using alert only for example

Comment: @mody: "2" is spelled _"two"_, not _"tow"_

Comment: @mody this should work normally for what you need to do

Comment: oh finally i find valid answer .. thank you  .. please vote my question

Comment: Vote your question!  Seriously.  Wow.

Answer (score 3):

There's absolutely no point in passing the data from HTML.

You're binding that function to the button's `id`. That `id` *must* be unique, so there's only ever that single combination of values.

Just use this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    alert('hello' + 'word');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="button">click</a>
```

Or, if you *want* to send the data from the HTML, you're going to have to do something like this:

```js
function mf (data1, data2){
    alert(data1 + data2);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="button" onclick="mf('hello','word');">click</a>
```

Or, if you *want* to use jQuery, you're going to have to do something convoluted like this:

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
    var data = $(this).data('params').split(',');
    alert(data[0] + data[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="button" data-params='hello,word'>click</a>
```

Comment: my value not fixed i have many button each of ther have value

Comment: @mody - your building buttons dynamically?

Comment: i want with jquery

Comment: @mody: why do you _want_ to use jQuery?

Comment: Fix the typo mistake on second snippet ... name of function

Comment: I have not received any valid result from any answer yet

Comment: _"my project requerd it"_: That's not a good reason to use jQuery. Any way, the last snippet in my answer should work for you, @mody.

Answer (score 1):

Following code should do the trick:

```js
function myf(data1, data2) {
  alert(data1 + data2);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a id="button" href="#" onclick="myf('hello', 'word');">click me</a>
```

return false; is to prevent default action.

Comment: No, now you're passing the result of `myf('hello','word')` to `.on`. That's literally the same as `$("#button").on("click", false);`

Comment: no i want send from onclick to jquery and do not fixed value

Comment: Edited my answer, still any problems with it?

Comment: @mody Now the values are bound purely on the id the click was bound on.
If you now add other clickable items you can change the function call in their click handlers.

Comment: @Peter-Paul: That doesn't fix the problem I told you. The problem is in the `.on("click", myf('hello','world'))`. That doesn't work.

Comment: hello word is not fixed value i want jquery function get value from button @Peter-Paul

Comment: My bad, this should be what you're trying to do. Added it as a code snippet.

Comment: Please don't include jQuery if you're not using it.

Comment: Which is basicly the same as Cerbrus 2nd example.
Dont forget to point him as the correct answer .

Answer (score 0):

As said you have already a listener, I don't see the point of adding an other one.

```
<button onclick="myf('hello','word')">click</button>

<script>
function myf(data1,data2){
  alert(data1+data2);
}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wnd6ovkf/

And the jquery version:

```
<button data1= "value" data2= "value2" class="btn">click</button>
<button data1= "ohtervalue" data2= "othervalue2" class="btn">click</button>

<script>
$(".btn").click(function() {
  alert(this.getAttribute("data1") + " " + this.getAttribute("data2"));
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wnd6ovkf/6/

Comment: i know this sir .. i want with jquery

Comment: @mody added jquery as asked.

Comment: hello word not fixed value it changing .. i want send data from button function to jqure and jquery display it

Comment: @mody I think this is what you want.

Comment: Develop your latest own code so that you send two values to the jammer through only one button. In order to agree to your answer

Comment: @mody Here you have it.